# Having to reference the model when using a Needs controller

Tags: ember.js, controllers

Don't know what's going on suddenly, but where I have a `needs: ['project']`, I now have to do `controllers.project.model.property` instead of `controllers.project.property` as worked before, which is also how the guides show it. Anybody have a clue as to why I'm having to put `model` in there now?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. In 1.11, proxying is deprecated, and usually you get a deprecation warning. However, I had made an empty `project` controller (extended from Ember.Controller), and doing that somehow suppressed the deprecations, so I wasn't seeing any, but couldn't figure out why my controller wasn't working. So when I removed that empty controller file, then the deprecation warnings popped up saying I should use 'model.property' instead of just 'property.'

Comment: Right On. It's might take a while to migrate your project and remove all deprecations, but I think the goal behind this, is to make it more obvious where the attributes come from. Much easier to debug afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, I really like the versioning model the core team is following. I'm slowly getting hip to all the lingo, but it's been a very slow process learning from the ground up.

Comment: All please note that `needs` is eventually become deprecated in favor of `Ember.inject.service` or `Ember.inject.controller`

Comment: Yep, I'm slowly migrating things up to 1.13. Just recently got all deprecations cleared on the 1.11 move. Very happy to see controllers and views go away in exchange for components and services.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the initializer deprecations? I have a question opened for this, so if you know the answer i'd appreciate your help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508348/fixing-initializers-deprecation-in-ember-1-12-0

Comment: @QuantumLicht: I haven't gone to 1.12 yet, so I haven't hit that one, although I probably will seeing as I do have similar code.